# Is there a method to predict the size of a .doc?

Tags: file-upload, ms-word, storage, filesize

I'd like to know if there is a way to predict the size of a .doc based on the number of pages it contains.

I'm trying to form a rough estimate of how much storage space I need when anticipating X number of .doc's of Y page length.

For example: "I need to plan for 100 .DOC files, each being 15 pages in length. These .DOCs will consume roughly _KB of space."

Thanks

Comment: What if one page contains a 100MB photo (scaled down to fit on the page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. There's too many variables.

For example, a .doc (Word 2003) containing a page of nothing but the character 'a' in one font takes up 37kb, in another the same number of characters takes 32kb, in another 43.

The most practical way would be for you to average the sizes of the sample files, and work off that, but be aware that the smallest change can have rather large effects.